# Remove duplicate key and value from json in java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am mapping `Object` (i don't have control over) to `jsonString`, after mapping I get duplicate key-value pairs in the JSON,
example

```
 {
 "id":"123",
 "email":"someEmail@gmail.com",
 "UserName":"someOne",
 "EMAIL":"someEmail@gmail.com"
 }
```

the duplicate is exactly the same except that it is in uppercase letters.
I am trying to get a `jsonInString` format without the duplication. Something like this:

```
 {
 "id":"123",
 "email":"someEmail@gmail.com",
 "UserName":"someOne"
 }
```

I have tried

```
String jsonInStringWithOutDuplication=mapper.enable(
    JsonParser.Feature.STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION).writeValueAsString(users);
```

with no luck, any suggestions?

Comment: they are not duplicate, you need first to arrange your hashmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't find a way to configure the `ObjectMapper` to filter out duplicate attributes, you can serialize the problematic object to JSON, then serialize the JSON to a `Map` object, merge duplicate attributes and serialize it to JSON again:

```
Map<String, String> objectWithDuplicates = new HashMap<>();
map.put("name", "MyName");
map.put("email", "em@ail");
map.put("EMAIL", "em@ail");

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

String jsonWithDuplicates = mapper.writeValueAsString(objectWithDuplicates);
Map<String, Object> attributesWithDuplicates = mapper
        .readValue(jsonWithDuplicates, Map.class);

Map<String, Object> withoutDuplicates = new HashMap<>();
attributesWithDuplicates.forEach((key, value) -> {
    if (! withoutDuplicates.containsKey(key.toLowerCase())) {
        withoutDuplicates.put(key.toLowerCase(), value);
    }
});
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(withoutDuplicates);
```

Comment: Thank you @JánHalaša that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson's ObjectMapper has a feature that puts the same keys into an array. Isn't it something that could help you?

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new GuavaModule());
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);    
Multimap resultAsMultimap = mapper.readValue(json, Multimap.class);
System.out.println(resultAsMultimap);
```